# Background not showing behind floating divs

Tags: css, html

what's wrong with this code?

The background disappears behind the divs when I add `float: left` to `#text` and `#text2`. But when I remove the `float: left`, everything looks good.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#first{
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #345752;
}
#left_b{
 background:transparent url('img/left.png');
 background-position: left top;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
  min-height: 30px;
}
#right_b{
 background:transparent url('img/right.png');
 background-position: right top;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#text{
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
}
#text2{
 float: left;
 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "first">
   <div id = "left_b">
      <div id = "right_b"> 
         <div id = "text">text 1</div>
         <div id = "text2">text 2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You container div `#right_b` is collapsing because its children are floating. You can fix this with the "Clear-Fix" technique. You may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for a few solutions:

- [Which method of ‘clearfix’ is best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

One popular solution is to add `overflow: hidden` to your container div: `#right_b`:

```
#right_b {
   background:transparent url('img/right.png');
   background-position: right top;
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Another common one is to add a `<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>` before closing your container div:

```
<div id="first">
   <div id="left_b">
      <div id="right_b"> 
         <div id="text">text 1</div>
         <div id="text2">text 2</div>
         <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give `#right_b` also a minimal height:

```
#right_b{
 background:transparent url('img/right.png');
 background-position: right top;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 min-height: 30px;
}
```

Float elements are took out of the normal document flow, so if an element does not contain other "normal" elements, this element has a height of `0` (as it has no content).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
.group:after {
  clear:both;
}
.group {
  zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

And add the class "group" to your "right_b" element, this will fix the collapsing div:

```
  <div id = "right_b" class="group"> 
     <div id = "text">text 1</div>
     <div id = "text2">text 2</div>
  </div>
```