# IE7 background color issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone tell me why the background color 'black' isn't being picked up on the footer of this website in IE7?

http://james-gilmore.co.uk/index.html

Comment: Usually, on Stack Overflow, we expect people to include relevant code in their post. This will ensure that even after the problem is fixed, future visitors will be able to learn from the post. In addition to posting the code in your question, you could also make a jsfiddle which may make people even more likely to help you.

Comment: What's that jQuery attribute that's being applied to the footer tag? Try removing that and see if it works?

Comment: thanks jdwire in future I will make sure I do this

Comment: @BillyMoat Those are the jQuery expando properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200722/jquery-expando-properties

Comment: @andyb - Ah, hadn't come across that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the hasLayout bug - have a quick read of this:

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Try adding height:1%

Answer (score 1):

The footer container has all floated children inside and therefore has no height. You need to *clear* the floats. There are [many ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best), ranging from adding a [**clearfix**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) class to the container or simply adding `overflow:hidden`

Also related - [Background not showing behind floating divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623769/background-not-showing-behind-floating-divs)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth just using the hex value `#000000` instead of `black`, and see if that fixes the issue.

IE7 is pretty lame sometimes...